# why is crystal report not displaying fields when joined entity is null

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

In my crystal report, which is linked to a `SQL Server Database` via a `DataSet (*.xsd-File)`, I am displaying data from several tables. It also has some sub reports.

In the main report, I display data from two tables. When there is a record to display for both tables it works, but when there is only a record in the first table and the corresponding record in the other table is null (which is ok), it displays none data.

Example:

Let's say I have a table `Person` and `Address`. A Person can have an Address, but it can be empty (null) as well.

When I want to display a report for a `Person`, which has an `Address`, it displays all wanted `fields` `(like Person.Name, Person.Age, Address.Street etc.)`.

If I want to display a report for a Person, which has no Address, it obviously cannot display any address data, but it also doesn't display the person's fields.

What could be the cause for this?

Can I improve my question to clarify something? I am using VS2010.

Comment: is there a query that you have already on the server that filters the data for the report ? sounds like a Query issue if so then create another query that meets your criteria

Comment: I only have the automatically created queries in the xsd-File, as far as I know, but I'll double check

Comment: There are only the selects to the tables, without any joins in the TableAdapter Configuration Wizard

Comment: you have your solution then Philipp M you will need to add an additional query / join or create a new one using the configuration Wizard..

Comment: ok, I will try to figure that out and let you know

Comment: it's not as difficult as it sounds .. you just have to make sure if you add to the existing with a different query name..that you reference it properly in your code I otherwise you will scratch your head trying to figure out why it points to the old query.. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I found out what was wrong DJ KRAZE, I didn't have to add a query, but change the join type. Thanks for your suggestions anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out, what was wrong and did the following to correct it:

In Visual Studio 2010, when you opened the rpt-File, click in the menu on Crystal Reports and open Database > Database Expert...
There you have to switch to the Links tab and there I had to **reverse** the link between my two tables and change in the link options the Join Type from "Inner Join" to "**Left Outer Join**".

After I did that, it worked as I expected.

Comment: That's a great.. I am glad that you were able to fix your issue.. great job